# How can i display more than one file with different file extension in UIWebView/UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I did google too much to find it but not find what i exactly want.
I have file.png, file1.jpg, file2.pdf, file.txt and file.doc and i want to preview this all file in one 
`UIWebView` or `UIScrollView`.
Please help me how can i do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it QLPriview Controller

Comment: Other wise Creating On HTML (string)Page including all files load in UIWebView

Comment: Do you have any sample code?
FYI : I also need total page count.

Comment: For Example image showing through HTML sting , This image in bundle file . The HTML sting load in webview   NSString *imageFileName = @"images";
    NSString *imageFileExtension = @"jpg";
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFileName ofType:imageFileExtension];
    NSString *imgHTMLTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\" />", imagePath];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:imgHTMLTag baseURL:nil];

Comment: This is the sample Once try get more information any web designer and I am update my post for two images one pdf showing (this is not exact way)

Answer (score 0):

For Example image showing through HTML sting , This image in bundle file . The HTML sting load in webview follow this ! as like you need creating html sting with all files and display

```
 NSString *imageFileName = @"images";
    NSString *imageFileExtension = @"jpg";
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFileName ofType:imageFileExtension];
    NSString *imgHTMLTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\" />", imagePath];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:imgHTMLTag baseURL:nil];`enter code here`
```

Once Check this

```
 NSString *imageFileName = @"images";
    NSString *imageFileExtension = @"jpg";
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFileName ofType:imageFileExtension];
    NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Disciplinary" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSString *imgHTMLTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\" /></body><body><img src=\"file://%@\" /></body><body><img src=\"file://%@\" /></body></html><body><object id =\"PDFObj\" data=\"file://%@\"/ type=\"application/pdf\" width = \"1000\" height = \"10000\"></body>", imagePath,imagePath,pdfPath,pdfPath];
    [img loadHTMLString:imgHTMLTag baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I think you are not clear with my requirement, i want to load file.png, file1.jpg, file2.pdf, file.txt and file.doc in single view(Webview/scrollview)

Comment: Yes this one step only ! you creating HTML string with all file like above example and load to webview

Comment: Ok check if any problem I will help you

Comment: Its only opening one document. :(

Comment: Total page count means

Comment: Suppose i have attached two pdf files(both pdf have same pages 5) and two image files as per your code then total pages will be 5+5+1+1 = 12.
So my main requirement is that and if i have attached rtf or doc file then how can i count page for it?