# Preview more than one files and Images in one Webview iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an array of files having extension (.pdf, .jpg etc). I want to load all these files in `WKWebview` when click a button. Can anyone guide me, how can I achieve this? I googled, but not getting satisfying way.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just create a Class that contains a WKWebView and array of files then place a next button and previous button on Header. First time user it will show the file on first index in the array then on next Button click Reload the WKWebView by next index item from array. You need to main the indexing of files with correspondence of next and previous button. Also add Activity Indicator when on Delegates StartLoading and FinishLoading of WKWebView.

Comment: I don't want to put previous and next button. I want them all to scroll vertically. For example when we are loading one pdf having multiple pages, same with multiple files. @Pandey_Laxman

Comment: You can put swipe gesture for left and right then reload contents from NSArray

Comment: I also tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794357/how-can-i-display-more-than-one-file-with-different-file-extension-in-uiwebview) , but not working